# What are the inorder postorder preorder of this binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to find a binary tree which all of its keys are different but the three traversals inorder postorder inorder are the same so i thought of this tree:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
```

So basically there are no left sons
But i am not sure if that would lead to similar three traversals

So is postorder=inorder=preorder = 1234 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-order means that a parent is always visited *after* ("post") its children, so the output 1, 2, 3, 4 violates that rule. Post-order for that tree will be 4, 3, 2, 1.

Pre-order means that a parent is always visited *before* ("pre") its children, so then the output is as you have it: 1, 2, 3, 4.

In-order means that a parent is always visited *after* its left child and *before* its right child -- coming "in" between them. As there are no left children in your example input, the in-order traversal is the same as the pre-order traversal.